# Create an array of Squares in opengl c++

Tags: c++, arrays, opengl

I want to create a memory game in opengl , so I create some square (3*3)

by two for like this:

```
for (float i = 0; i < 3 ; i++)
{
    for (float j = 0; j < 3 ; j++)
    {
        glPushMatrix();
        glTranslatef(+j/9,-i/9,0);
        squre1();// create a cell
        glPopMatrix();
    }
}
```

I want to change color of some squares randomly ,after 2 seconds those cells change to before color,and user should remember witch cell is changed and click on it ...

So I want each square selective and know witch cell is clicked.
The simple solution is use array for manage my work but how do it?

Comment: Use `int` instead of `float` when possible...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Baisc OpenGL does not manage mouse events, you should go for [GLUT](http://www.opengl.org/resources/libraries/glut/spec3/spec3.html) or [SDL](http://www.libsdl.org/release/SDL-1.2.15/docs/html/guidevideoopengl.html) to achieve user input control.

**EDIT:** As Vallentin points out in his comment, GLUT is outdated, and suggest to take a look also on [GLFW](http://www.glfw.org/).

Comment: Don't use GLUT, use GLFW instead!